# Search for negative numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, search, numbers

I want to get the count of the negative numbers saved in a mysql table. 
Ex: I want to get total numbers of withdrawals and value from the account within last month.

I know that this can be done using extra row. But I want to do this without changing the table structure. I tried with "WHERE Amount < 0" but didn't work. Any help please.

Comment: Showing the table structure will definitely make this question a better one.

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE Amount<0;
```

Comment: It did not worked when I tried with "Amount < 0". But now it working. I think some internal error. BTW thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
select count(0) from test where id < 0
```